# How can I go one path up and append a new url in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My current path is 
`app/get-main/123/add-sub/`. I want to navigate to `app/get-main/123/get-sub/123`. Currently I am doing this by

`id=123;
this.props.history.push('/get-main/123/get-sub/'+id )`

How can I achieve this in a better way, where in I go up one level from current route to `app/get-main/123/` and then append `add-sub/id`

Answer (score 2):

You can get your current url path using this.props.history.location.pathname so you can do:

```
this.props.history.push(`${this.props.history.location.pathname}get-main/123/get-sub/${id}`)
```